# How can I get the id of inserted row in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code and the error:

[image]

As you can see, I've tested the insert statement like `if ( $inserted )`, but `id` isn't into that object. How can I fix it?

---

And here is my code:

```
    public function register_guarantee_ticket()
    {
        $problem = json_decode($_COOKIE['guarantee_ticket']);

        $guarantee_tickets = new guarantee_tickets;
        $guarantee_tickets->unique_product_id = $problem->unique_product_id;
        $guarantee_tickets->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $guarantee_tickets->submit_time = time();
        $guarantee_tickets->brick = !empty($problem->turn_on) ? 1 : 0;
        $guarantee_tickets->title = $problem->title;
        $guarantee_tickets->description = $problem->description;
        $guarantee_tickets->tracking_code = DB::select("SELECT LEFT(UUID(), 8) as random_unique_string;")[0]->random_unique_string;
        $guarantee_tickets->status_id = 1; // waiting ...
        $inserted = $guarantee_tickets->save();

        if ($inserted){
//            echo "ticket registered";
            $ticket_id = $guarantee_tickets->id;
            return \redirect()->route('list_of_ticket')->with($ticket_id);
            unset($_COOKIE['guarantee_ticket']);
            setcookie('guarantee_ticket', null, -1, '/');
            // redirect to user's panel, in the ticket list
        } else {
            $status = "register-unique-device-alert-danger";
            $msg = "something went wrong, try again";
            return \redirect()->route('form_serial_number')->with($status, $msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you assigning a variable for the inserted info? You can just call save() on the item, the ID will be automatically saved to the object

Comment: It's better if you post your code here, not an image. `$inserted` is just the true/false success value from saving your `$guaranteed_tickets` object. Get your ID from that.

Comment: @musefan I intended to show both the code and the error message Laravel throws.

Comment: @musefan Ok, I will also add my code.

Comment: @aynber Right .. thank you

Comment: Can you post the code to your model? Especially your attributes.

Answer (score 2):

```
$guarantee_tickets->save();
$inserted = $guarantee_tickets->id;
```

This will do it.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying a bad approach to get this thing work you can directly access the id with the variable you made as the object of the model to save the value which is '$guarantee_tickets'

And access the id like:

```
$id = $guarantee_tickets->id;
```

because nothing will be there in the $inserted variable

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check what is `inserted`, because you check it in the `if` statement, but it is probably an object that will not return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `public $fillable = [ 'unique_product_id", "user_id", /* other fields */ ]` on your `guarantee_tickets` model as probably it won't save the fields in database unless you set the fillable field into the model.